# Show popup when user is inactive after 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, html, user-inactivity

I am trying to show pop up when the user is inactive for 5 minutes.

```js
  timeout() {
    setTimeout(() => this.openDialog(), 4000);
 }
```

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Alert!</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true"cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

In the code above the `this.openDialog()` dialog displays when you open the page after 2 seconds. But I want to display the pop up when user is inactive for 5 minutes.

Comment: What's not working? Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: TylerH this.openDialog() dialog opens the page after 2 seconds when the page loads,but i want to display the pop up when user is not accessing webpage after 5 minutes.

Comment: There is a `SyntaxError` running your Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a variable that will track the number of milliseconds user hasn't done any activity

Check for any mouse or keyboard activity - reset timer to 0 when it happens
Here's an example that will wait 5 seconds instead of 5 minutes

```
var idleTime = 0

document.addEventListener('mousemove', resetIdleTime, false);
document.addEventListener('keypress', resetIdleTime, false);

function resetIdleTime ()
{
    idleTime = 0    
}


function checkIfIdle ()
{
  idleTime += 1000
  console.log(idleTime)
  if (idleTime >= 5000)
  {
    alert("Inactive for 5 seconds")
    clearInterval(idleInterval)
  }  
}

var idleInterval = setInterval(checkIfIdle, 1000);
```

Question wasn't that clear. Are you trying to check if the tab hasn't been focused on in 5 minutes? inactive on page for 5 minutes? either way, the above should point you in the right direction

Comment: sqram,i tired to pass the model pop instead of alert i am gettting the following error.this.openDialog is not a function.can you convert the above code typescript.the above code is fine i need this typescript?

Comment: when i pressing the keybord activity it is not working

Comment: @njeo  "error.this.openDialog is not a function"  is a problem else - make sure you're including the file where the function is defined, or define the function in the document somewhere. And no, I've never done Typescript, but the code above is very simple, it should be easy to convert. -- also, code has been updated to fix the keypress typo

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let timer;

function time() {
timer = setTimeout(() => {
     console.log(5000)
}, 5000) 
}

time();

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  time();
})
```

Comment: @HCK,I tried your code but it is showing alert if i  am filling some details

Comment: I've just updated the formatting of the answer. The person who posted this answer is @Noobs_Nobby